# Conditional configuration: How to detect if I'm local or online?

Tags: php

I want to provide different configurations for local and offline. At the moment, every time I upload my stuff to the web server, I must make sure that I don't mess up with the different config files. One for local development, and one for online.

I slightly remember a couple of years ago, a code snippet distinguished somehow automatically between online and local development.

Is there a safe way to detect that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally use the server name, for that ; for example, here's what I use on my blog :

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] === 'blog') {
    // Development
} else {
    // Production
}
```

This is because :

- On my development machine, the blog is accessed via `http://blog` *(nothing else after)*, using a `VirtualHost` with a `ServerName` directive.
- On the production server, of course, the `ServerName` directive is a bit longer than this, containing the actual blog server name.

Comment: It was close : I have answered less than one minute before you ^^

Answer (score 2):

I have build this function that checks if current **server name** has **name server** records, normally local server don't has.

```
<?php
function isLocal ()
{
  return !checkdnsrr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'NS');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: Set up a .htacces file in your development root:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

Then read it:

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')
                                    ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')
                                    : 'production'));
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is basically the same as Pascal’s on this page, but since you may change your development server name and you may need several of this checks in your code, i prefer doing this:

```
define ('DEV_HOST', 'blog'); // if you just use http://blog locally
```

And then check

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == DEV_HOST) {
  // do your tricks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that requires zero configuration and should work pretty fast:

```
function isOnline()
{
    return checkdnsrr('google.com', 'ANY');
}
```